# How come ivars don't have attributes the way properties do

Tags: ios, objective-c

How come properties have user settable attributes for storage and lifetime, but ivars don't.  Especially considering the fact that a property is backed by an ivar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instance variables *can* have attributes, such as `__strong`, `__weak`, `__unsafe_unretained`, etc.

Also, as others have noted, properties are about *behavior*. They declare accessor methods and calling an accessor method is invoking behavior. Also the property is *interface*, while instance variables are *implementation*. As such, properties communicate the design contract to clients of the class. That's not necessary with instance variables, since clients should ideally be ignorant of implementation details.

Comment: Very interesting... so if ivars can have attributes as you indicated, what are the defaults if you don't specify anything?

Comment: The default is `__strong`. I should clarify that those attributes only apply to object pointer types, not to something like `int`.

Comment: So if I were to declare a property to hold a weak reference to a UIView, then if I don't use a property and instead only use an ivar, should I declare that ivar as __weak ?

Comment: Yes, but there's little reason to not use a (private) property.

Comment: Ohh, ok... private property.. I'll do that then.  Excellent.

Answer (score 4):

Properties are not always backed by an ivar. Properties are just promises to implement accessors. If you don't implement the accessors yourself, then the system will automatically write some for you (called "synthesizing"), and will create an ivar as an implementation detail. The attributes you're describing are instructions to the compiler about how you want the synthesized accessors written.

Prior to ObjC 2, we wrote all our accessors by hand. Properties and synthesized accessors were added later to automatically implement patterns that had been long established at that point.

Comment: I would argue that synthesis of accessors and instance variables are a secondary characteristic of declared properties. The primary purpose is declaration of interface. They'd still be useful if the compiler didn't provide synthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Because the effect of a `@property` is basically a superset of what you get by declaring an instance variable. With  `@property` you're telling the compiler to create an instance variable along with accessor methods. The extra details tell it how those accessors should work. With an instance variable you're just declaring the ivar and leaving it at that.

Comment: The property is really just the promise of accessors. If you fulfill that promise yourself, no ivar will be created (which often surprises people).

Comment: Ok thanks.  I guess I've been confused because when one thinks of lifetime of a variable, one might consider that you might use an attribute to indicate that if you're only declaring the variable itself, and no accessor methods.  But I guess WHERE you declare the variable determines its lifetime, scope, storage attributes, etc.